# How to load texture in jsfiddle

Tags: three.js

How to use THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture() in jsfiddle. I have created a demo [ http://jsfiddle.net/georgeneil/cfrsj/10/ ]. Here I am not able to view the texture. I am getting the points rendered as black.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [base64 encode](http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64/) the image. And then add the string in your code.

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cfrsj/11/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cannot use a texture that is hosted externally. Here is some code I created to put a texture on a plane. I believe I adapted this code from one of mr doob's projects:

```
img = new Image();
texture = new THREE.Texture(img); 
    img.onload = function() {
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    makeParticle();
    };
img.src = "http://www.aerotwist.com/tutorials/creating-particles-with-three-js/images/particle.png";

geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 438, 695, 200 );
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map: texture} );
```