# three.js - textures not loading

Tags: javascript, three.js

**CONTEXT**

I'm trying to recreate the example shown [here](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap_refraction) using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yjsug38q/). I'm using this code to load the array of textures:

```
        var r = "https://github.com/timoxley/threejs/tree/master/examples/textures/cube/Park3Med/";
        var urls = [
            r + "px.jpg", r + "nx.jpg",
            r + "py.jpg", r + "ny.jpg",
            r + "pz.jpg", r + "nz.jpg"
        ];
```

I am only trying to recreate the texture, not the ply. Is there any reason why this wouldn't be working as I've set it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer is correct in stating the error, but misses a simple solution. You can load cross origin image data with Three.js. You just need to set it up properly. Here's the example fiddle with  the fix: https://jsfiddle.net/1dy343xy/

The code change:

```
    var loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();

    loader.setCrossOrigin( 'anonymous' );

    var textureCube = loader.load( urls );
```

Also note you were pointing to bad urls. You need to use git raw urls for what you're doing, although I don't know if it meets git ToS.

Comment: Thank you for the help on this - both solutions worked but this one wins for flexibility. Follow-up: is there a reason why the camera rotation is not being controlled by movement on mobile (I mean on a separate site, not jsfiddle)?

Comment: I've seen this implemented here, but not alongside with mouse movements: http://richtr.github.io/three.js/examples/misc_controls_deviceorientation.html

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with security. You could serve your project on an apache or node server. And you will not have this problem anymore.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - is there a workaround for this? Can you elaborate a bit? Closest answer I see is this, but not quite clear what solution is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753720/how-to-load-texture-in-jsfiddle

Comment: Is this a cross origin policy issue? So it should work fine if everything is on same domain?

Comment: Yep, it has to do with security. Not sure why I got down voted. You could serve your project on an apache or node server. And you will not have this problem anymore.

Comment: Edited, im on my phone thats why I made the answer short. My own fault...

Comment: @Modig the URLs he was using were bad and would return HTML if anything at all. There was no way to confirm a cross origin issue with the urls in use. Even if he put the code on his own apache or node server, it would still fail. The images would have to be hosted on the same server with the original javascript for your answer to work, and so does not answer the question. I didn't vote you down, but I imagine that answers your query as to why someone may have voted it down.